# Cannot connect to wifi with Lenovo G510 wireless under Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04

My laptop model is Lenovo G510 which is not able to detect wireless.

When I output of `ifconfig -a` I can not see any wireless such as `wlan`. My ubuntu version is `14.04`.

How can I install the driver and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same laptop :). If your card is a Broadcom 43412 or similar, you will need the `broadcom-wl` package. To get it, use `apt-get install broadcom-wl`. On reboot, wifi will start working. Otherwise, try `modprobe wl` in the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. i don ot have any internet connection such as cable .how to download that from windows and installing in ubuntu?

Comment: Ummm, download this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/broadcom-sta-common. PS: Haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working with `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source*`

This package can be installed even without a working internet connection, since it is present on the ubuntu install disc, under the 
`<mount point for the ubuntu install disc>/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source*.deb`

Its prerequisites are the following (also present on the install disc):

```
/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms*.deb

/pool/main/f/fakeroot/libfakeroot*.deb

/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot*.deb
```